# how to design better efficient looping using underscore + ES 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

Below are my two arrays.

```
let clientCollection = ["1","ABC","X12","OE2","PQ$"];



let serverCollection = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Ram",
    "Other": "Other properties"

},
{
    "Id": "ABC",
    "Name": "Shyam",
    "Other": "Other properties"

},
{
    "Id": "OE2",
    "Name": "Mohan",
    "Other": "Other properties"

}]
```

Now I am in need to compare the above two collections & create two sub arrays

```
let matchedIds = []; 

let unMatchedIds = [];
```

Now this is what I am doing currently.

```
for(let i =0 ; i < clientsCollection.length;i++)
{
    if(_.indexOf(serverCollection, clientCollection[i]) >= 0)
    {
          matchedIds.push(clientCollection[i]);
    }
    else
    { 
        unMatchedIds.push(clientCollection[i]);
    }
}
```

In my application, the size of these arrays can increase to 1000 or more. This could be have efficieny issues

I am using underscore & tried if I can get some better solution but couldn't find yet.

Can someone please suggest if I can do the same in better efficient way using **underscore + ES6**??

Comment: Your initial solution does not work (populating is wrong due to `_.indexOf(serverCollection, clientCollection[i])`  ) but combination of `for` and  underscore `indexOf` is not so bad... See my answer, it satisfies the issue and it is pretty fast.

Comment: @dhilt, yes, I am analyzing your plunkr link attached Thanks :)

Comment: A new information has arrived. Increasing the collection size strongly affects my current solution. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this would be a good way for `matchedIds` population:

```
for(let i = serverCollection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const id = serverCollection[i]['Id'];
  if(clientCollection.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
    matchedIds.push(id);
  }
}
```

And this one is for `unMatchedIds` after the `matchedIds` is done:

```
for (var i = clientCollection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (matchedIds.indexOf(clientCollection[i]) === -1) {
    unMatchedIds.push(clientCollection[i]);
  }
}
```

None of `filter`, `reduce` etc is faster than basic `indexOf`!

**UPD** 
I created a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UcOv6SquUgC7Szgfn8Wk?p=preview. He says that for 10000 items this solution is up to 5 times faster than other 2 solutions suggested here.

Comment: You're still looping over the entire collection and then `indexOf` for each item. The comparison should be between `indexOf` and `Set.has`, and [`Set.has` is much faster](https://jsperf.com/array-indexof-vs-set-has).

Comment: This is only true when you have very few items in the `clientCollection`. See [plunkr with more items](https://plnkr.co/edit/tyVMAXrx9py5EuiXn7QR?p=preview). As the collections grow in size, this solution will become slower.

Comment: Please, try 100k or 1M items on my plunker, you'll see that even your new try is 2+ times slower than mine.

Comment: Oh, make sense! you increased array length... yes it's the good point

Comment: You aren't adding items to the collections, you are simply running the same few items many times. Please see my plnkr that adds only 100 items, it becomes extremely slow. Your solution is `O(n*m)`, as the two arrays grow the will become increasingly slow.

Comment: thanks :) i agree your solution is better in many cases of fewer items

Comment: Thanks too, it was a pleasure to deal with you!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from all the server ids. Then just loop through and see if the id is in the `Set` and add it to the two arrays:

```js
let serverCollection = [
  {
    Id: '1',
    Name: 'Ram',
    Other: 'Other properties'
  },
  {
    Id: 'ABC',
    Name: 'Shyam',
    Other: 'Other properties'
  },
  {
    Id: 'OE2',
    Name: 'Mohan',
    Other: 'Other properties'
  }
];

let clientCollection = ['1', 'ABC', 'X12', 'OE2', 'PQ$'];
const serverIds = new Set(serverCollection.map((server) => server.Id));

let matchedIds = [];
let unmatchedIds = [];

for (let id of clientCollection) {
  if (serverIds.has(id)) {
    matchedIds.push(id);
  } else {
    unmatchedIds.push(id);
  }
}

console.log('matched', matchedIds);
console.log('unmatched', unmatchedIds);
```

As the length of `clientCollection` and `serverCollection` increases, the cost of looping through each item becomes more and more apparent.

See a [plunkr measuring performance](https://plnkr.co/edit/tyVMAXrx9py5EuiXn7QR?p=preview)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, your code doesn't work. It only populates matchedIds list and populates it wrong. I tried it in console... ?

Comment: I see that you're creating Set from serverCollection but I am wondering if we create set from clientCollection as well?? Will it boost in anyway

Comment: This is how clientCollection array is build   `let clientCollection =
                self.productIds.toString().trim().split("\n");`

Comment: Creating a set from clientCollection won't really help because you need to loop through the entire collection anyway, it's already efficient to loop through them in array form. If productIds has to be parsed from a string, there isn't much you can do to improve the speed there.

Comment: Okay. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of server ids. Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) to iterate the clients, and assign the id to a sub array according to it's existence in the server's set. Extract the sub arrays to variables using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring).

```js
const clientCollection = ["1","ABC","X12","OE2","PQ$"];

const serverCollection = [{"Id":"1","Name":"Ram","Other":"Other properties"},{"Id":"ABC","Name":"Shyam","Other":"Other properties"},{"Id":"OE2","Name":"Mohan","Other":"Other properties"}];

// create a set of Ids. You can use underscore's pluck instead of map
const serverSet = new Set(serverCollection.map(({ Id }) => Id));

// reduce the ids to an array of two arrays (matchedIds, unMatchedIds), and then get assign to variables using destructuring assignment
const [matchedIds, unMatchedIds] = clientCollection.reduce((r, id) => {
  r[serverSet.has(id) ? 0 : 1].push(id); // push to a sub array according to existence in the set
  
  return r;
}, [[], []])

console.log(matchedIds);

console.log(unMatchedIds);
```

Comment: Is *your* `serverCollection.map(({ Id }) => Id)` equal to `serverCollection.map(x => x.Id)`?

Comment: Indeed it is. I find that destructuring reduces the noise.